# Rigging dragon wing

Tags: animation, rigging

So I'm trying to model and rig a dragon, and I was stumped when coming across the wings. [image]

As can be seen here, as the wing opens, the "fingers" spread farther from each other. How can I create this effect?

Comment: It's not a dragon but a bat and very similar: https://youtu.be/v4SG-GQesRw

Comment: ill check it out thx

Comment: they "spread farther from each other", could you please be more precise?

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/2394ad81e5aa49bca78d181bdea4ce9f this is what im going for, but for this i moved each bone individually

Comment: you could use the Copy Rotation constraint, it allows you to rotate only one bone and the other ones will follow, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: maybe, ill give it a try

Comment: it didnt work. what i want is that as i rotate one bone, the others fan out behind it

Comment: nvm i figured it out thx so much @moonboots

Comment: so did you succeed with Copy Rotation?

Comment: yes, i did. the problem was that i had influence set to 1, but lowering it gave the effect i wanted